# Incorrect Syntax Near ELSE

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will  print a list of customers and the brands they have bought. The report produced by the procedure must use the following format:

```
Customer Last Name1
```

BrandName1

BrandName2
               ...

Customer Last Name2

Brands

Customer Last Name3

Brands

The Customer and Brand tables are separated by Invoice, Line and Product tables.  I've used joins to link them together, but I'm getting a syntax error in my code while using an IF and ELSE, and I can't figure out why it would be wrong.

```
       CREATE PROCEDURE CustomerList

   (@Cust_LName VARCHAR(20), @Brand_ID INT = NULL)
   AS
   BEGIN

    IF(@Cust_LName IS NULL)
    DECLARE Customer_Cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT  DISTINCT C.Cust_LName, B.Brand_Name
        FROM    LGCustomer C
        LEFT JOIN LGInvoice I ON C.Cust_Code = I.Cust_Code
        INNER JOIN LGLine L ON I.Inv_Num = L.Inv_Num
        INNER JOIN LGProduct P ON L.Prod_SKU = P.Prod_SKU
        INNER JOIN LGBrand B ON P.Brand_ID = B.Brand_ID
        ORDER BY C.Cust_LName ASC
        OPEN    Customer_Cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM Customer_Cursor INTO @Cust_LName
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE Brand_Cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT  Brand_ID
        FROM    LGProduct
        WHERE   Brand_ID = @Brand_ID
        OPEN    Brand_Cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM Brand_Cursor INTO @Brand_ID
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT @Brand_ID
        FETCH NEXT FROM Brand_Cursor INTO @Brand_ID
    END
    CLOSE Brand_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE Brand_Cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM Customer_Cursor INTO @Cust_LName
    END
    CLOSE Customer_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE Customer_Cursor

    SELECT  *
    FROM    LGCustomer

    ELSE
    BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    FROM    LGProduct
    WHERE   Brand_ID = @Brand_ID
    END
    END
    GO
```

I've tried removing the END's before the ELSE, and removing the IF and ELSE themselves, but if I do that, it doesn't display the results how I want them to be shown.  I'm relatively new at SQL, so I'm really not sure where I went wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: it looks like you are missing the begin and end to your first if statement

Comment: I've never said this before, but there is so much wrong with this that you are not close enough to help. It isn't a syntax error, you don't know enough about what is going on in this language to produce this. You need someone with some experience in SQL to spend some time (4 hours) with you.

Comment: While I appreciate your very constructive input, I got it fixed and it produced exactly what I wanted it to.  So thanks to everyone who assisted me.

Answer (score 0):

TRY LIKE THIS , Allign your code by block you should be able to figure out.

```
IF(@Cust_LName IS NULL)
BEGIN

...
...

END
SELECT  * FROM    LGCustomer
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT  * FROM    LGProduct WHERE   Brand_ID = @Brand_ID
END
END
GO
```